# Avoid using complicated strings in Joins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, join, data-warehouse

I will create a couple of tables in SQL Server for a client. Of special interest for this question is the `FactStoreSale` table to be created and `DimProduct` in which the first table will include all store's sales and include for instance `StoreKey`, `DateKey`, `TimeKey`, `ProductKey` and sales data.

The `DimProduct` table will use complementary data in regards to Products, i.e. `ProductName`, `ProductGroup`, `ProductCategory` etc. This table will be a slowly changing dimension, and store Product history in terms of price etc. for each store. The table will include the columns `FromDate` and `ToDate` which describes when the data was entered, and when it was replaced (with default value year 2999 in `ToDate` until a new update of the Product is inserted) respectively.

I Believe this is very common. However, the `ProductKeys` from the underlying database are very complex strings, such as `140-xx4449CH-4.44,9`.

My alternatives as I see it, is to use `Checksum` in SQL Server to convert the complex strings to integers, and store these in a separate column `ProductKeyInt`
and use these columns when doing JOINS. But checksum does not guarantee unique integer values, which would likely cause problems. When I tried Checksum on a Virtual PC and my own PC, doing Checksum  on the same values returned different results which is a concern as well. I Believe these two together rules out Checksum, unless it can be manipulated somehow to make it more unique?

Another  alternative is to use more complex functions to ensure that the string values are converted into integers, such as the one provided on a  question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251834/convert-strings-to-integers-using-patindex). A solution such as this however also has issues, the values `100-xx3` and `1003` will for instance get the same result. It is also complicated in the sense that if someone who isn't that savvy in SQL need to try to find any issues with the Query that uses the function, it may be very hard to understand what is happening.

My third option seem to be to use the `DimProduct` table and update this table first from the SQL Agent, and using an Indexing Key on this table and use this index as the  ProductKeyInt in the `FactStoreSale` table (where ProductKeyInt will be some kind of subquery in for instance `FactStoreSale` to fetch the value with the biggest `ToDate` in DimProduct corresponding to the ProductKey.

Does anyone have any input? Is there a simpler way? I don't want to have strings as JOIN keys because of for example [increased CPU time](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't need to use the `ProductKey` column as *the* key column in `DimProduct`. You can create a surrogate key that is a composite key made up of `DimProductID` that is an `IDENTITY` column and increments per each row of the SCD, and a `ProductID` column that is unique per each `ProductKey`. Both would be `INT` (most likely, unless you will never have very many unique products, in which case I might opt for `SMALLINT` for `ProductID` which gives you 65k values to use).

   This approach allows you to have both the ability to reference any particular version of a product (using the `IDENTITY` column, or both as both will probably work with indexes better), *and* the ability to aggregate over all versions of a particular product using just the non-`IDENTITY` column.

   In either case, you generally don't need to be JOINing on the `ProductKey` column / value.
2. When you do need to filter or JOIN on `ProductKey`, assuming that there is no functional difference between upper-case and lower-case letters, you should force everything to be upper-case *and* use a binary Collation (any Collation ending in `_BIN2`, not `_BIN`, though most likely `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`). Most people do not consider the Collation being used for string columns that contain alpha-numeric codes where there is no purpose, in any way, for having case (or Kana or width or accent insensitivity) and no purpose in evaluating complex linguistic rules, such as which character sequences equate to other characters in other languages. Non-binary Collations have A LOT of complex rules that they apply, and those take time. Using a binary Collation will be *much* faster as it just compares the bytes, which is why you need to force upper-case just in case someone enters in an alpha character in lower-case.

   So for this, make sure to set the column's Collation to use `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` when creating the table. If the table has already been created, use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` to set the Collation so that it will be used by default.